# Selecting the odd or even elements out of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've been asked to write a piece of code that returns the odd elements of an array when a the second argument is `true` and even elements if it is `false`. So far I have written one half and I need a method that can select the odd elements.

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  if return_odds != false
    string.chars.to_a
  end
end

puts odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", true)
```

Comment: Your "one half" won't even work. :) `!=` instead of `=!`.

Comment: hahah schoolboy error! sorted that bit now :)

Comment: What array are you mentioning? You seem to be passing a string to the method.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add this code you have 2 handy methods to select odd or even values from an array

```
class Array
  def odd_values
    values_at(* each_index.select(&:odd?))
  end
  def even_values
    values_at(* each_index.select(&:even?))
  end
end
```

Comment: Good piece of code. `.select{|i| i.odd?}` and `.select{|i| i.even?}` can be shortened to `.select(&:odd?)` and `.select(&:even?)`

Comment: `self.` can be omitted.

Comment: Very nice! One thing I like about `values_at` is that it reads so well. A variant of `odd_case` would be to replace `values_at`'s argument with `*(1...size).step(2).to_a` (and change the `1` to `0` for `even_case`), ala @falsetru's answer.

Comment: I had forgotton that [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at)'s argument can be a range, so you can drop `to_a` in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Array
  def odd_values
    e = [false, true].cycle
    select { e.next }
  end
  def even_values
    e = [true, false].cycle 
    select { e.next }
  end
end

arr = "Here is a simple illustration of these methods".split

arr.odd_values
  #=> ["is", "simple", "of", "methods"]
arr.even_values
  #=> ["Here", "a", "illustration", "these"]
```

Comment: Yes, @Wand, I am fond of enumerators generally, and `cycle` in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  start = return_odds ? 1: 0
  (start...string.size).step(2).map { |i| string[i] }
  # OR  string.chars.values_at(*(start...string.size).step(2))
end

odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", true) # => ["b", "d", "f", "h"]
odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", false) # => ["a", "c", "e", "g"]
```

Comment: Indices 0, 2, 4, ... are even numbers, not odd. But I am not sure if the OP meant 0-based or 1-based counting.

Comment: @sawa, Thank you for pointing it out. I updated the answer accordingly. (to match with oldest answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  string.chars.select.with_index{|_, i| return_odds ? i.odd? : i.even?}
end

odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", true)  # => ["b", "d", "f", "h"]
odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", false) # => ["a", "c", "e", "g"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some excellent answers here on finding even and odd numbered characters, but if you ever needed the flexibility to find other types of numbers, you may end up rewriting with something more 'crude' such as this:

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  new_string = string.chars.to_a
  even_odd_string = []

  new_string.each_with_index do |letter, index|
    if return_odds != true && index %2 == 0
      even_odd_string << letter
    elsif return_odds != false && index %2 == 1
      even_odd_string << letter
    end
  end
  even_odd_string
end

puts odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way this can be done:

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  string.chars.each_slice(2).collect {|pair| return_odds ? pair.last : pair.first }
end

p odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", false)
#=> ["a", "c", "e", "g"]
p odds_and_evens("abcdefgh", true)
#=> ["b", "d", "f", "h"]
```

Another variant can be:

```
def odds_and_evens(string, return_odds)
  indices = (0...string.size).select {|i| return_odds ? i.odd? : i.even? }
  string.chars.values_at(*indices)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is okay but it’s slow.

This is 2-3 times faster. Also, it does not monkey-patch the Array class hence it can be used on other objects, for example, ActiveRecod::Relation

```
def self.even_elements(list)
    list.values_at(*0.step(list.size - 1, 2))
end

def self.odd_elements(list)
    list.values_at(*1.step(list.size - 1, 2))
end
```